# Can't use rqt_plot with some topics

Tags: roscpp, rostopic, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm not able to use `rqt_plot` with some topics (I'm using ROS Indigo).
I this it's because I can't find the correct field name and so I'm not able to correctly specify the path in `rqt_plot`.

This is my [bag file](http://www.skeetty.com/plot.bag) and, for example, it outputs the following data for /robo/io topic:

```
data: 1511957429.218142138,0,0,0,0,3416,1441,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6551
---
data: 1511957429.318112290,0,0,0,0,3442,1169,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6552
---
data: 1511957429.418157183,0,0,0,0,3345,1283,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6553
---
data: 1511957429.518295379,0,0,0,0,3294,1374,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6554
---
data: 1511957429.618295945,0,0,0,0,3294,1306,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6555
---
data: 1511957429.718757851,0,0,0,0,3258,1366,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6556
---
data: 1511957429.818196624,0,0,0,0,3307,1473,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6557
```

This is the result of `rostopic type`:

```
rostopic type /robo/io
std_msgs/String
```

All the topics included in the bag file come out from a ROS node which I wrote.

I'd like to plot columns 6 and 7 of `/robo/io` by using `rtq_plot` or any other tool available under ROS.
Can you help me, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277203/can%27t-use-rqt_plot-with-some-topics/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2017-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-04**:
Random comment: using `std_msgs/String` for this seems like a really strange thing to do. And I would be surprised if the answer by @jayess works immediately. I'm not sure if `rqt_plot` will plot anything but numeric data and / or can index into strings like what is suggested.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-04**:
@gvdhoorn Good point, I somehow missed that `std_msgs/String` part at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rqt_plot` will only plot one entry in an array so, if you want to use it, you need to specify which entry you want to plot. Therefore, you should try something like:

```
rqt_plot /robo/io[5]
```

or

```
rqt_plot /robo/io[6]
```

Alternatively, you can start `rqt_plot` and at the top enter the topic name and index of the array.

[Note that I didn't download your bag file because I don't download random files from random sites on the internet. So, you may have to play around with what you need to type in order to get the plot but this should be a starting point for you.]

---

**Update**

As @Dirk Thomas pointed out in the comments you can combine the two commands:

```
rqt_plot /robo/io[5] /robo/io[6]
```

---

**Update 2:**

As @gvdhoorn noted in the comments, you're trying to plot an `std_msgs/String` value which will not work. Plotting numbers makes sense. Plotting strings? Not so much.

If you're publishing the data then maybe you want to re-think how you're doing it (i.e., publish numerical data types). If you're not publishing and only subscribing, then you'll want to transform this data from a string into a numerical data type.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-12-03**:
You can also pass multiple topics to plot multiple lines at the same time: e.g. `rqt_plot /robo/io[5] /robo/io[6]`.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-03**:
@Dirk Thomas: thanks, I'll add that.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2017-12-04**:
You have reason, I cannot plot string data. I need to change the code for my node in order to publish numerical values.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-04**:
Great. If this solved your problem then please click the checkmark button to accept it.